# What is `ISeqable` in Clojure and how does it relate to `ISeq` (`clojure.lang.ISeq`)

Tags: clojure

In *Joy of Clojure*, 2nd edition, page 217, we read:

> You may have noticed that we've been using our own function `xseq`
>   throughout the examples in this section, instead of Clojure's `seq`.
>   This shouldn't be necessary, because Clojure provides an `ISeqable`
>   interface that its `seq` function can use - all you need to do is to
>   have your own type implement `ISeqable`.

The text then proceeds to declare a type protocol-implementing an `ISeq`, more precisely

```
(deftype InfiniteConstant [i]
   clojure.lang.ISeq
   (seq [this]
      (lazy-seq (cons i (seq this)))))
```

Apart from the mis-use of the the word "interface", which is a concept from the Java-level, instead of "protocol", which is a concept from the Clojure-level, is `ISeqable` a real concept or is it something that was left uncorrected during editing?

The index lists "ISeqable interface" only for that very page, and "ISeq interface" for another page.

Comment: You can do a web search at https://github.com/clojure/clojure or clone and grep the repo. There is no ‘ISeqable’.

Comment: Presumably this is supposed to reference [`clojure.lang.Seqable`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Seqable.java) instead of `ISeqable`.

Comment: @Lee Possible, but then it's still an confusion of Clojure and the Java implementation underneath. Needs rewrite for 3rd edition, I would say. (The book an excellent read, but it is not making clear how much of Java is poking "up" into the design of Clojure, possibly leading to ugly/complex tradeoffs that would not be needed or even desirable in a fresh implementation. But perhaps that's asking too much.)

Comment: `ISeqable` is a real thing, but maybe it only lives in Clojurescript. https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/ISeqable

I recently received an error message in Clojurescript "is not ISeqable". Presumably, there is no difference in Clojure or Clojurescript for this aspect of the language. The link above points back to `Seqable`.

Answer (score 1):

In the Clojure implementation (which is written in Java), the interface is Seqable, which indicates a type that can provide an ISeq (also a Java interface).

In ClojureScript (which came later after protocols were added to Clojure), most of the core interfaces are implemented as protocols instead, like ISeqable.